# ArrayAdapter onResume() confusion

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have a class `MyArrayAdapter` which extends `ArrayAdapter<MyClass>`.
Now I have a `MyListFragment` which extend `ListFragment` which uses the `MyArrayAdapter`.
Class `MyActivity` adds the `MyListFragment` in the view.

So far so good.

Now, the user can change preferences, upon which I need to change some Strings in the `List<MyClass>`. Since the ArrayAdapter only recognizes `onNotifyDataSetChanged()` when its own methods like `clear(), add(), etc` are used on the `List<MyClass>` which I am not doing,  I use the onResume to reload the data to reflect the changes.

So my `MyListFragment` contains the following:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private List<MyClass> elements = null;
    private MyListAdapter myListAdapter = null;

    public MyListFragment(List<MyClass> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.foo, elements);
        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        myListAdapter.clear();
        myListAdapter.addAll( sqliteclass.getAllElements() );
        myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isSecondTime = true;
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

This works but the problem with this is when the activity runs the first time, that there are now **2 trips** to the database where one is required. So I modified the class as below:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private List<MyClass> elements = null;
    private MyListAdapter myListAdapter = null;
    private boolean isSecondTime = false;        //NEW

    public MyListFragment(List<MyClass> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.foo, elements);
        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if(isSecondTime){       //NEW
            myListAdapter.clear();
            myListAdapter.addAll( sqliteclass.getAllElements() );
        }                       //NEW
        myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isSecondTime = true;
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

So my question is, is the hack that I am doing by using **boolean isSecondTime** to make sure that the first time I don't make 2 trips to the DB reliable? The adapter saves the list of elements, so the second time onwards I make only one trip.

(Eg. If the user changes the preferences, switches to some other app, and Android decides to free some memory, and removes the `MyListFragment` from the memory, and when the user switches back, can I be assured that the `List<Elements>` will be fresh from the db? - This or any similar scenario)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: why are you using ArrayAdapter if your data comes from (at least the name sqliteclass suggests so) sqlite? use SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: Sounds good. I will see if `SimpleCursorAdapter` suits my need more closely and get back..

Comment: Consider looking into SimpleCursorAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should store your `Adapter` in `Activity`, populate it only once at start and become independent of `Fragment's` lifecycle. Make a getter for it and access it from `Fragment` via `(MyActivity) getActivity().getMyAdapter()`.

About your second question: if user switches to another app, there are 3 possible scenarios:

1. User comes back quickly, nothing is changed.
2. User comes back after a while, your app was cached and restored -
       still you'll get the same state of objects.
3. User leaves your app for a long time, it's killed. App'll have to
       restart from scratch.

In all cases, you're safe.

Answer (score 0):

I always do this in onResume()

```
public void setList() {
    Log.i("setList","");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
    if (items.size()<1)
        adapter.add(getString(R.string.emptylist));
    for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++) {
        adapter.add(items.get(i).item);
    }
    todolist.setAdapter(adapter);
    for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++) {
        todolist.setItemChecked(i, items.get(i).checked);
    }
}
```

I add a new adapter every time I need to update the list.

Comment: Yes, that is an option, but adding a new adapter everytime needs a lot of resources and also uses a lot of Garbage Collection. So I want to avoid that.